# How can I find the highest value of a particular node within a multidimensional JSON object with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, object

Here is a short sample of the object I am working with.

```
{
    "myservices": [
        {
            "name": "oozie",
            "hostidn": "1",
            "details": "failed process health monitor....",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "name": "oozie",
            "hostidn": "2",
            "details": "failed process health monitor....",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "name": "oozie",
            "hostidn": "3",
            "details": "failed process health monitor....",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "name": "oozie",
            "hostidn": "4",
            "details": "failed process health monitor....",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "name": "oozie",
            "hostidn": "5",
            "details": "failed process health monitor....",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "name": "single-namenode",
            "hostidn": "2",
            "details": "failed process health monitor....",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        }
    ]
}
```

I ultimately want to find what the highest "hostidn" is before running through all these and displaying them. hostidn is a Nth number it can be the only number or it can be hundreds deep with several duplicates in between. My Goal is to find that highest one and do a for or while loop on it based on that to group them together in a visual display. Example notice I have one hostidn below with the number 2 while all the rest have there own. I would want to group the two with 2 together in a box for display but there is 5 different hostidn in this scenario. I dunno maybe I am thinking it over wrong I'll take suggestions however.

Comment: is the question that you want to display all the ones with the highest hostidn, including dupes?

Comment: Do you want to get the highest number or the number which occurs the most? In any case, you have to iterate over the array and compare the numbers, so what's your actual problem?

Comment: Well basicly I want to display all the ones including dupes based on the hostidn. The hostidn in this case will act as a container that will then show each one with the same hostidn in that container. Issue here is the hostidn can be anything from 1 to 200+ so I don't have a set number to work with. The other issue is the way they output in the object is to say the least random So I have to find the highest number so I can run a while like loop based on low to high the numbers will always be in order to my knowledge meaning no gaps in the count. I just don't know what the high number is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic algo you can follow

declare and set a variable to zero like

$currentHighest=0;

then iterate over the json array and on each iteration campare the value of `hostidn` with the `$currentHighest` if the value is higher than the value already existing in the `$currentHighest` set that value to `$currentHighest`

```
$currentHighest=0;
 $(data.myservices).each(function(index, element){
   if(data.myservices[index].hostidn>$currentHighest)
     $currentHighest=data.myservices[index].hostidn;
  });
//loop ends and `$currentHighest` will have the highest value
```

at the end of the iteration you will get the highest value in the `$currentHighest`

**Tried and tested**

```
$(function(){
 $.post("highest.json",function(data){
 $currentHighest=0;
  $(data.myservices).each(function(index, element){
   if(data.myservices[index].hostidn>$currentHighest)
     $currentHighest=data.myservices[index].hostidn;
  });
alert($currentHighest);
},'json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns an array containing one or more objects with the highest idn. Also see http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/DUTK7/ (logs to console)

```
function getHighHostIdn (json) {
    var i = 0;
        hostidns = [],
        len = json.myservices.length,
        highest = null,
        matches = [];

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        hostidns.push(parseInt(json.myservices[i].hostidn, 10));
    }

    highest = Math.max.apply(null, hostidns);

    for (i = 0, len = hostidns.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (hostidns[i] === highest) {
            matches.push(json.myservices[i]);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use linq.js for these kind of things, it allows you to avoid many traditional for loops in your code (visibly). Sure you can probably write more optimized code for each use case, but for most things performance is not so important and the cleaner/shorter code is a greater benefit.

If there is only chance for one max value, or if you don't care which one you get, as long as its the one that have the max value, then do something like this:

```
var result = Enumerable.From(obj.myservices).MaxBy('$.hostidn');
```

Or if you can have and want multiple max objects, then do this:

```
var e = Enumerable.From(obj.myservices);
var result2 = e.Where('$.hostidn == ' + e.Max('$.hostidn')).ToArray();
```

You can see the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/sTaHv/13/ 
EDIT: I also added a sorting example since I saw that you mentioned that.

To read more about linq.js go to the project page: http://linqjs.codeplex.com/